# Searching users by country, and have the result summed pr. country

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I am trying to use `Get-AQDUser` to get a summed list of users per country. So far a have this

```
$Country = Read-Host "Please Enter the country of which you want to see users "
Get-QADUser -ObjectAttributes @{co="$Country"} | ft displayname, co -auto
```

and this lists the user names perfectly, but not summed.  To get them summed i added the following to above

```
| Measure-Object
```

This gives me the number of users, but it counts 4 more users than there is.  If I search for users in ADUC, it gives me the correct number.  I also tried with the `.Count` parameter, but this also gives me 4 more users, than there actually are.
And i am searching from the root of our AD.

Any idea, why `|measure-object` always gives me 4 users too many?

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer when its a good one ;-)  Keeps the community in good holiday spirits!!

Answer (score 2):

`Measure-Object` measures *whatever* is piped into it, in your case, the output of `Format-Table`.  This means `Measure-Object` will *measure* the table, including the headers, separators, etc., as well as the values.

Example:

```
Get-ADUser jscott | Measure-Object
Count    : 1
...

Get-ADUser jscott | Format-Table | Measure-Object
Count    : 5
...
```

Exactly four extra. You should probably just skip the `Format-Table` until you want to display the output values on-screen, after you've counted them. Using your example, the following should return the correct number of users:

```
Get-QADUser -ObjectAttributes @{co="$Country"} | Measure-Object
```

Comment: Wow, that simple, never thought of trying that. Thanks a bunch